# How do I retrieve the Linkedin API for my company page?

Tags: api, linkedin-api

I have installed the LinkedIn Campaign Manager app to our MA tool Eloqua but to configure it I need the API for our LinkedIn company page and I do not know how to retrieve it? Can someone help me?

BR,
Josefine

Answer (score 0):

To retrieve the API for your LinkedIn Company Page:

```
> Sign in to Campaign Manager.
> Select the account you would like set up with data integration.
> Click Tools in the top navigation bar.
> Click Matched Audiences.
> Select the Uploaded list audiences tab.
> Select Connect to data integration.
>Review the terms and click Next to view API Keys
```

Let me know if this helps, BR, Sheressa